# How to create dependencies between 2 build pipelines in Azure DevOps and link a work item to build pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline

The second build pipeline should be dependable on first build pipeline and the work item should relate to the build pipeline for keeping track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to create dependencies between 2 build pipelines in azure Devops and link a work item to build pipeline?

There is an option [**Build Completion**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/apr-03-vsts#chain-related-builds-together-using-build-completion-triggers) under **Triggers** in your build definition:

> Large products have several components that are **dependent on each
>   other**. These components are often independently built. When an
>   upstream component (a library, for example) changes, the downstream
>   dependencies have to be rebuilt and revalidated. Teams typically
>   manage these dependencies manually.

So, we could use this option to set up dependencies.

And there is another option [Automatically link new work in this build](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/automatic-linking-work-items-to-builds/) under **Options** in your build definition, which could use to track the related workitems.

As test, I created a pipeline `nullTest` which depend on `nullTest2`:

[image]

And enable the option `Automatically link new work in this build` for those two pipelines, after the completion of the construction pipeline `nullTest2`, the `nulltest` pipeline is triggered:

[image]

**Update:**

> Could you give me a step wise procedure how to associate the work
>   item?

Associate the workitem to the pipeline, you just need add associate the workitems when you submit the changes:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried integrated in build to associate the work item. But only a specific build number gets added into the work item details. How do you I associate a work item completely wit build so that each time I run the build, it is displayed in the development section of work item. I enabled the automatically link work item, but still I don't get the related work item after running the build. Could you give me a step wise procedure how to associate the work item?

Comment: @SiddhiDilipKamat, I have updated my answer, please check if it helps you.

Comment: @ Leo Liu-MSFT Thanks for your response. This only works when commits are done from the remote repository and not local repository. Could you please clarify this for me?

Comment: @SiddhiDilipKamat, you mean from Visual Studio? If yes, I will check.

Comment: @SiddhiDilipKamat, I test it with Visual Studio, it also works fine.

Comment: Yes, I mean Visual studio community edition. I tried but it doesn't work. Could you suggest something?

Comment: @SiddhiDilipKamat, I am using the Visual Studio **Professional 2019**, seems to be a problem with the VS version, do you have other versions of VS to test? I don’t have a community version at this moment, and testing it will take some time to install it

Comment: @SiddhiDilipKamat, Also test it with Visual studio community 2019, it works fine. Try to update your VS to 2019 and test.

Comment: @Leu When I commit the changes from the local repo and push it onto devops for the first time with new project. How should I link the commit to work item? or How can I associate a new build with commit from local repo to work item. Sorry for delay in reponse. Thanks